# How do I write a PowerShell cmdlet to take either a HashTable or a PODO for input?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have a powershell module that wraps around some web services. The web services take complex Plain Old Dot Net Objects (PODOs) and I have been using [HashTables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) as in cmdlet parameters and *[New-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315334.aspx) MyPODO -Property $MyHashTable* to transform the hashtable into the request object like so

```
function Get-Stuff ([HashTable]$WhatStuff) {
    $service = New-ServiceProxy . . . .
    $request = New-Object GetStuffRequest -Property $WhatStuff;
    return $service.GetStuff($request);
    $response;
}
```

However, sometimes I have a cmdlet whose response object can directly become a request object like so:

```
function Find-Stuff ([HashTable]$KindaStuff) {
    $service = New-ServiceProxy . . . .
    $request = New-Object GetStuffRequest -Property $KindaStuff;
    return $service.SearchStuff($request);
}
```

Is there some sort of way to decorate the $WhatStuff parameter to accept either a HashTable or a PODO of a particular type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[James Tryand](https://twitter.com/#!/monkeyonahill) gave me this answer in [a tweet](https://twitter.com/#!/monkeyonahill/status/114366390873493504).

The answer is to use [Parameter Sets](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/12/23/powershell-v2-parametersets.aspx).

In one paramater set you accept a parameter of type HashTable, and in the other one, you accept the PODO type.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like below, depending on how you want to use it:

```
function Get-Stuff ($WhatStuff) {

    if(($WhatStuff -isnot [HashTable]) -or ($WhatStuff -isnot [PODOType])){ throw "expect it to be Hashtable or object of type"}

...
}
```